# Create Python PATH

Tags: python, path, pip

I'm trying to do pip installs, but I get errors saying "is not a recognized as an internal or external command", so I tried following the guide below, but after creating the PATH and typing "Python" in the CMD, I still get "Python is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/4

I installed python from https://www.python.org/downloads/

Also, I'm not sure if this has an effect or not, but I do already have Anaconda installed on my computer, but I need to use PyCharm, which is why I'm trying to "reinstall" Python.

[image]

Comment: have you added python to your windows system environent variable ?

Comment: If that's the same thing as in the guide where it says "Edit envrionment variables for your acocunt", then I did that, but nothing was resolved afterwards.

Comment: just find in your system where python is located in anaconda, copy that path, in pycharm go to settings>add interpreter>give path there

Answer (score 0):

Since you have anaconda and you intend to use PyCharm, I would strongly recommend you to use the conda environment as the interpret in PyCharm, unless you want to use other virtual environment management tools.

If you insist to use the system Python, what you should do is

1. Add the system python path into your environment variables
2. Ensure you have removed other python path (such as anaconda) in your environment variables

To better help you, you could share your environment variables here.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey,

I'm very new to Python and I'm not sure what all these terms mean. How can I locate my environment variable to share? Is it the path I created in "Edit envrionment variables for your account"?

Comment: I just typed "pip install selenium" in the anaconda prompt and also installed a few other libraries and it seems to be working. However, when I try to run my python code in PyCharm it says that there is no interpreter selected. Could you please provide guidance?

Comment: yes that's right, Environment variables are those inside 'Edit environment variables for your account'. But in your second comment I guess you are good with anaconda environment, so let's go from there. You could go to pycharm settings, search for project interpreter, that's where you could select the anaconda environment. The dropdown list should be able to show your conda env automatically, just select that.